# how to update order summary sidebar after dynamic product addition from checkout page

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, addtocart, knockoutjs, guest-checkout

I have added a product to the cart through knockout js if the guest customer checked the option during checkout. I was able to update the mini cart also. But I could not update the Order summary sidebar. So even if I have added or removed the product from the cart it is not dynamically affecting the sidebar. Only if I refresh the whole page then only correct data is loading in the sidebar.

Do anyone know how to call the sidebar update through knockout js file "shipping.js"?

Any Ideas or suggestions for this requirement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you manage to find any solution I am currently looking for this thanks.

Comment: @JulianoVargas: not yet.

Comment: I found that adding this to the ajax request success it updates the summary block however it give error if not in checkout page so need to check if is only check out page to run the code :var deferred = $.Deferred();
                    getTotalsAction([], deferred);  Let me know if find anything